# Why do I have an error of "IndexError: list index out of range" when I do TF-IDF using pyspark.ml.feature?

Tags: python, pyspark, tf-idf

Here is my codes:

```
def dataPreprocessing(data):
    splitData = data.map(lambda line: line.split('`'))
    getData = splitData.map(lambda line: [labelMap[line[2]], list(jieba.cut(line[6]+line[13]))])
    return getData

trainSql = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataPreprocessing(trainData)).toDF('label', 'raw')
testSql = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataPreprocessing(testData)).toDF('label', 'raw')

remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="raw", outputCol="filtered").setStopWords(stopWord)
filteredTrain = remover.transform(trainSql)
filteredTest = remover.transform(testSql)
filteredTrain.cache(); filteredTest.cache()

tf = HashingTF(numFeatures=20000, inputCol='filtered', outputCol='rawFeatures')
trainTf = tf.transform(filteredTrain); testTf = tf.transform(filteredTest)

print trainTf.select('rawFeatures').take(5)

idf = IDF(inputCol='rawFeatures', outputCol='features')
idfModel = idf.fit(trainTf)
trainIdf = idfModel.transform(trainTf) ; testIdf = idfModel.transform(testTf)
trainIdf.show()
```

And because I am dealing with chinese text, I use the python package jieba for splitting word. The output of line "print trainTf.select('rawFeatures').take(5)" is right. The error comes with IDF, and the error as follows:

```
16/07/25 16:12:49 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 7)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lyj/Programs/Apache/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
process()
  File "/Users/lyj/Programs/Apache/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/Users/lyj/Programs/Apache/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File      "/mypath/classfication.py", line 20, in <lambda>
getData = splitData.map(lambda line: [labelMap[line[2]], list(jieba.cut(line[6]+line[13]))])
IndexError: list index out of range

at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:129)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
```

What should I do?

Comment: right before `getData = ...`, make sure that all elements of `splitData` have at least 14 elements ... `for spd in splitData: if len(spd) < 14: print spd`. That will tell you from what data your error comes from (if that is the problem)

Comment: @ Julien Spronck Thanks, it does have this problem.